# Is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS compatible with Alienware Aurora R7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

I am new to linux and ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS dual boot with Windows 10 on an Alienware Aurora R7 on the same HDD over a year ago and I've experienced. I have a secure boot on, I have both UEFI and RAID on instead of legacy and achi. I've been experiencing both issues with fatal kernel errors when I was shutting down from Ubuntu but I was told that you just need to restart to windows 10 and shutdown from there. But since yesterday after trying to work with scikit-learn and restarting, I can no longer start Ubuntu from GRUB as fatal kernel exceptions occur. I can also no longer boot into a recovery ubuntu kernal or older kernels.

So I am wondering, is Ubuntu or other form of linux compatible with the Alienware Auruora R7? If so, do I have the mode sets incorrectly (I installed both OSs on my HDD), do I need to repair my Ubuntu, or do I need to remove my Ubuntu OS? Please let me know or if anyone can help, please provide tips or guides below.

Thanks